# htaccess Can't open files uploaded on server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, file-upload

I am uploading mp3 files to my website through a script, but when i try to either download them or play them with an HTML5 player, they don't run.

The download file link looks like this :

```
http://test.entreplus.com/content/plugins/post_audio/uploadify-local/uploads/Mac.(Miller)!%20-%20Jerry's%20Record%20Store.mp3
```

And when i'm trying to download it, it redirects me to the main page.

It only happens on the live site, although in localhost it works fine.

Could someone be awesome enough to have a look at my .htaccess file and see if the problem is in there?

```
Options +Indexes +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

## Redirect www.example.com to example.com. Add ## if you don't need the redirect.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

AddType application/x-shockwave-flash swf

# BEGIN EXPIRES
#cache html and htm files for one day
<FilesMatch ".(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=43200"
</FilesMatch>

#cache css, javascript and text files for one week
<FilesMatch ".(js|css|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
</FilesMatch>

#cache flash and images for one month
<FilesMatch ".(flv|swf|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>

#disable cache for script files
<FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
Header unset Cache-Control
</FilesMatch>
# END EXPIRES

<IfModule mod_gzip.c>  
    mod_gzip_on Yes  
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes  
    mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$  
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$  
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text\.*  
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*  
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image\.*  
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*  
</IfModule>

##### CORE ADMIN #####
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ admin_index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ admin_index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/plugin_settings/plugin/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ admin_index.php?page=plugin_settings&plugin=$1 [L]

##### GENERIC RULES #####
RewriteRule \.(css|php|png|jpg|gif|ico|js|inc|txt|gz|xml|html)$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?$1=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?page=$1&$2=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?$1=$2&$3=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?page=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?$1=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6 [L]
```

Comment: try to exclude `.mp3` files from being processed i.e. add `mp3` to this as `RewriteRule \.(mp3|css|php|png|jpg|gif|ico|js|inc|txt|gz|xml|html)$ - [NC,L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as [Ulrich Palha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499472/ulrich-palha) wrote, is to

> exclude .mp3 files from being processed i.e. add mp3 to this as
>   RewriteRule .(mp3|css|php|png|jpg|gif|ico|js|inc|txt|gz|xml|html)$ -
>   [NC,L]